# MYSQL: Update date range to not overlap with lowest record in specific date range

Tags: mysql, date, range

I have been trying to figure out this query for the longest time but just cannot get it. Here is what I am trying to do:

I want to take this data

`+------------+------------+-------+
| StartDate  |  EndDate   | Value |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-31 |    10 |
| 2015-01-12 | 2015-01-15 |     9 |
| 2015-01-18 | 2015-01-19 |     8 |
+------------+------------+-------+`

And turn it into this:

`+------------+------------+-------+
| StartDate  |  EndDate   | Value |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 2015-01-01 | 2015-01-14 |    10 |
| 2015-01-12 | 2015-01-15 |     9 |
| 2015-01-16 | 2015-01-17 |    10 |
| 2015-01-18 | 2015-01-19 |     8 |
| 2015-01-20 | 2015-01-31 |    10 |
+------------+------------+-------+`

Any ideas on how I might go about this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What should be in the EndDate (Current Date?) and value columns ?

Comment: You could simply `INSERT` and `DELETE` the appropriate values. Or could you describe more generally what you're trying to do? What conditions for deleting/inserting values? What SQL code have you tried for this?

Comment: This is a complicated query and very, very difficult to do in MySQL.

Comment: @eirikir, I am using sql within vb.net code so I have created a loop that adds a record to a temp table for each day (1/1/2015, 1/2/2015, ..., 1/31/2015) then I use logic to compress it to get the results that I am looking for.

HOWEVER, this loop is very slow as it is inserting a record for each row 30 times. When my loop gets up to 1 million iterations, it takes way too long. I wanted to see if there is a way to do this without using a loop and just use a query which will be much much faster.

Comment: @rickymunoz As Gordon said, its going to be extremely difficult to make a single query for this. Its going to be easier to implement, easier to maintain, and likely faster to execute if you break it up into separate queries and use other code to manage it. Are you using PHP, Rails, or some other web framework? Or something else? Could you include the code you've tried so far?